# SQLyog creating foreign key error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm having a problem regarding SQLyog Foreign Key relationship creation when I execute this query:

**Error:**

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`zestagio`.`#sql-6dc_4b6151`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CARRO` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`CARRO`) REFERENCES `km_carro` (`IDCARRO`))

**MySQL Query:**

```
ALTER TABLE `zestagio`.`km_colaboradores`   
  ADD COLUMN `CARRO` int(11) NOT NULL after `TIPO`,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CARRO` FOREIGN KEY (`CARRO`) REFERENCES `zestagio`.`km_carro`(`IDCARRO`)
```

Comment: Is `km_carro`(`IDCARRO`) column declared as a Primary key?

Comment: Yes, When I created the other FOREIGN KEYS, it didn't gave me any error. Just on this one, I don't know why.

Comment: Please, post `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for `km_carro` and `km_colaboradores`. See [14.7.5.10 SHOW CREATE TABLE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html).

Comment: The problem existed because I had previous data inserted and it doesn't allow me to create foreign keys until there is no data on the table km_colaboradores. Thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message simply means that you have records in `km_colaboradores` table that do not satisfy the constraint set by `FK_CARRO` foreign key.

Seeing that the field `CARRO` is defined as `int` and `not null` and there is no default value specified either. The fact that this statement did not raise any error, but the foreign key did, indicates that strict sql mode is not enabled. You probably have data in the table already, so adding the `CARRO` field this way resulted in it being set 0 for all records. In strict sql mode this would have resulted in an error message already, therefore strict sql mode cannot be enabled.

However, when you tried to add the foreign key, then MySQL did not find any record in `km_carro` table, where `IDCARRO` were 0, therefore the existing records break the foreign key constraint.

I suggest to allow `CARRO` to have null values for the time being, add the foreign key, update `CARRO` values as required to proper values, only then disallow null values.

The other alternative is to define an explicit default value for `CARRO`, a value that exists in the `IDCARRO` field.